# Object follow path animation lags behind

Tags: animation

Is there a way in Blender to match the same f-curve of a path?
I have an object following a curve as a path animation. I tweaked the f-curve start/end mapping interpolation for the path, so it’s not exactly linear. But now the evaluation time doesn’t match.
Copying the f-curve doesn’t work either.

Any hints?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT578.jpg

And it also pivots at the beginning, and at the end of the animation.

Here’s the file, in case someone would be so kind to take a look.
https://file.io/aKkS3yid2nxo

Even setting the interpolation for both the geometry end factor, and the evaluation time as linear, doesn’t fix the problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: your link does not work

Comment: Not sure what happened with the blend file.
Here's an alt link
https://www.mediafire.com/file/tgw6fylddgzk3q3/follow_path_issue.blend/file

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't linked an image, it's actually a clip, and a blend file. I don't think it's possible to post those type of files here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure what's causing this....but...i just hope you are interested in solutions/workaround and not in "but why is it that way?" ;)

I just can assume that's because you are doing following a path which is animated at the same time.

So if you just copy your curve and hide it and then check "fixed positions" on that curve and animate the offset, it just works:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Chris!
I guess the Geometry End Factor needs to have a linear interpolation, or else it wouldn't work, right?
Quite strange behavior this one.

Comment: Honestly...i don't know. But if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thanks.

Comment: Sure. I actually had clicked on the arrow that's pointing up, apparently it didn't work.
I clicked on the checkmark.

Comment: Thank you and have fun with Blender!